# Excel VBA Count different Values from multiple Ranges

Tags: excel, vba, range

I want to find out different values ( text ) in 3 different ranges.
I think I found a way online, but it gives me an error.

Here are the codes;

```
Dim MyDict As Object, MyCols As Variant, OutCol As String, LastRowXY_2 As Long
Dim XY_A As Variant, I_XY As Long, MyData_XY As Variant

Set MyDict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
MyCols = Array("P", "S", "V")
OutCol = "AN"

For Each XY_A In MyCols
    LastRowXY_2 = Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Cells(Rows.Count, XY_A).End(xlUp).Row
    MyData_XY = Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Range(XY_A & "22:" & XY_A & LastRowXY_2).Value
    For I_XY = 1 To UBound(MyData_XY)
        If MyData_XY(I_XY, 1) <> "" Then MyDict(MyData_XY(I_XY, 1)) = 1
    Next I_XY
Next XY_A

Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Range(OutCol & "1").Resize(MyDict.Count, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(MyDict.keys)
```

At the second run of "XY_A", MyData_XY gives a "Type-Mismatch" error.

I can use any kind of idea.

Comment: check in debug mode in the second loop what is the value of `LastRowXY_2`

Comment: At the second loop, value of LastRowXY_2 is "22"

Comment: so now debug and see what are you getting (in debug mode) for `MyData_XY` (Empty)

Comment: At the debug mode, "For I_XY = 1 To UBound(MyData_XY)" gives an error. MyData_XY gives a value, but this row gives an error. ( again type-mismatch ) // "UBound" gives the type-mismatch error.

Answer (score 1):

**Option 1:**

Change:

`Worksheets(Ders_Sheet_Adi).Range(OutCol & "1").Resize(MyDict.Count, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(MyDict.keys)`

to

`Range(OutCol & "1").Resize(1, 1).Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(2)`

and check whether it works now. If it does, you don't have any values in `MyDict`, thus, it throws an error.

**Option 2:**
What do you think `MyData_XY` is? A range, an array?
Try to call it like this -> `MyData_XY(1)(1,1)` instead of this ->`MyData_XY(1,1)`

Comment: Thx for answer. Unfortunately, first option didn't have any effect because I get the error before that line. And I couldn't understand the second option I'm afraid.

Comment: @Bildircin13 - concerning option 2 - your array has arrays within it. You are referring it like this -> `MyData_XY(1,1)`. You should refer it like this `MyData(1)(1,1)`